# Mongo Compass 1.24.1 force replicaset topology discovery on connection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

While creating new connection on Mongo Compass the UI try to discover the entire replica set topology and connect to the primary/secondary IP.

Is there a way to create a DIRECT connection to an HOST/IP+Port just like the clients api and disable the topology discovery step?

From pymongo documentation:
directConnection (optional): if True, **forces this client to
connect directly to the specified MongoDB host as a standalone**. If false, the client connects to the entire replica set of which the given MongoDB host(s) is a part

Comment: Eventually compass will use a version of node driver that implements the directConnection option.

Comment: What driver its using today ?
https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/lib_mongo_client.js.html line 155 show this flag. And I wonder how it works OK on Compass 1.23

Comment: 1.24.1 uses 3.6.3 it seems.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to connect to a replicaset, use a `mongodb` connection string (as opposed to `mongodb+srv`), use a host IP / port, and drop the `&replicaSet=` parameter.

Comment: using the base connection string (mongodb://localhost:27017) still cause the problem. In the error I can see the real IP of the mongo instance. I am using tunnel from my MAC to the Mongo instance

Comment: When I try to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 I get the error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND 10.10.0.290

Answer (score 0):

A bug ticket was opened to Mongo on Jira
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/COMPASS-4534
The fix should be in version 1.42.2